# regexp add space after period but not when period represents a decimal or letter abbreviation?

Tags: php, punctuation, abbreviation

Using php regexp in a simple way, is it possible to modify a string to add a space after periods that follow words but not after a period that is preceded and followed by a number such as 1.00? I also need it to ignore single letter abbreviations such as N.Y.

```
String.Looks like this.With an amount of 1.00 and references N.Y.
```

Needs to be changed to...

```
String. Looks like this. With an amount of 1.00 and references N.Y.
```

This should allow for multiple instances within the string of course...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\.)([[:alpha:]]{2,})/', '$1 $2', $text);
```

Comment: P.S. There are a number of pre-built classes that you can use inside [].
And [:alpha:] means letters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/((?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\.(?=[A-Za-z]{2})|(?<=[A-Za-z]{2})\.(?=[A-Za-z0-9]))/
```

And the replacement string is `'. '`.

Note that the regex above expects at least one alphabetical character on one side of the full stop `.`, and expects alphanumeric character on the other side.

Test string:

```
"String.Looks like this.With an amount of 1.00 and references N.Y.Mr.NoOne.30% replaced.no 50.Don't know."
```

Output:

```
"String. Looks like this. With an amount of 1.00 and references N.Y. Mr. NoOne. 30% replaced. no 50. Don't know."
```