# python regexp add <br> after every 4th period

Tags: python, regex

I want to insert `<br>` after every 4th period, but not when period represents a decimal or letter abbreviation?

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127372/regexp-add-space-after-period-but-not-when-period-represents-a-decimal-or-letter), but since I'm new to regex, can someone guide me through how to write equivalent in Python??

For eg :-

```
'I'm a Python programmer. I love to code. I'm a boy. I earn $100.39 , from which I spend $50 in xyz. I eat biscuits. I eat snacks.I eat pizza etc. '
```

Expected O/P

```
'I'm a Python programmer. I love to code. I'm a boy. I earn $100.39 , from which I spend $50 in xyz.<br> I eat biscuits. I eat snacks.I eat pizza etc. '
```

Explanation -

Since `.` in 100.39 is not considered a period, it is actually a decimal, hence 4th period in this string is afer `xyz`

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Regex is not what you need here.

Comment: What could be an optimal solution??

Comment: As  seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127372/regexp-add-space-after-period-but-not-when-period-represents-a-decimal-or-letter , regex is used here...

Comment: How do you differentiate "The U.S. Dollar is strong." from "I immigrated to the U.S. It was not easy." ?  "U.S." ends a sentence in the latter but not the former.  It probably requires natural language processing to distinguish these cases.  Certainly it cannot be done with mere regexes.

Comment: As @MarounMaroun said, a regex is likely to be too complicated. Regexes are bad at context-awareness, and you need to know context to determine that "Dr.", "Mrs." or "etc." are not, in fact, sentence endings. You need a language parser, for example http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: Regex wouldn't be my first choice. The problem is actually quite complicated, since you have special requirements about letter abbreviations and decimals. Complicated regular expressions with that kind of logic are possible to write, but really hard to debug and understand.

Comment: Point accepted. So, how can I just add <br> after every 4th period using regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:.*?(?<![A-Z])\.(?=\s*[A-Z]|\s*$)){4})
```

Try this. Replace by `\1<br>`. See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/50

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'((?:.*?(?<![A-Z])\.(?=\s*[A-Z]|\s*$)){4})')
test_str = "I'm a Python programmer. I love to cX.Yode. I'm a boy. I earn $100.39 , from which I spend $50 in xyz. I eat biscuits. I eat snacks.I eat pizza etc. "
subst = "\1<br>"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

As told in comments there cannot be  foolproof regex which can do what you want, but if your input is fixed you can handle to some extent if you do not have any any other way. Here

We find 4 blocks of sentences by capturing anything upto `.` and then replacing it with `\1br`. But the `.` should not be a decimal so added a lookahead that anything following `.` should be space and a capital letter. To negate abbreviations added a look-behind that `.` should not have `a capital` letter behind it. This has pitfall though as it will fail in case of `U.S.` if this comes at the end of sentence.

Comment: Does not works for `Dr. Name`. Considers `Dr.` as period

Comment: how can I just add <br> after every 4th period using regex, not considering the decimal or abbreviated part.

Comment: @user1162512 you can add `(?<!Dr)` for that and for `Mr` `Mrs` as well.See here https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/53

Comment: Can you please explain the regex. I'm not good with it. Thanks

Comment: @user1162512 it should work.Can you show you are doing it at termnial.